# displaying django custom validation

Tags: django

Hi I am a newbie in Django, so I want to show some error message in html,

I have done methods in forms,

### def clean_FirstName(self):

---

But I want to show that error message near the first name textbox, how I will do it?

Comment: what kind of error message u want to show ?

Comment: bro  i have raised form.ValidationError("my error msg"), but i want to show this msg near my firstname textbox in html

Comment: can u share the code of view and template so i can easily help u